# JavaFX button background image

Tags: image, button, background, javafx

I have problem with setting backgroundImage on button in JavaFX.

```
Image newGame = new Image("File:/CSS/nova_hra.png");
BackgroundImage newGameBgr = new BackgroundImage(newGame, null, null, null, null);

Button buttonNewGame = new Button("Nová Hra");
Button buttonLoadGame = new Button("Načíst Hru");
Button buttonStatistics = new Button("Statistiky");
Button buttonExit = new Button("Konec");

buttonNewGame.setGraphic(new ImageView(newGame));
//buttonNewGame.setBackground(new Background(newGameBgr));

buttonExit.setMinHeight(40);
buttonLoadGame.setMinHeight(40);
buttonNewGame.setMinHeight(40);
buttonStatistics.setMinHeight(40);

buttonExit.setMinWidth(120);
buttonLoadGame.setMinWidth(120);
buttonNewGame.setMinWidth(120);
buttonStatistics.setMinWidth(120);
```

This does nothing with the buttonNewGame. Every time I tryed to load image with this

```
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("a.png"));
```

I got runTime exception. When I used

```
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("a.png"));
```

the whole image disapeard.

Comment: Is there any difference between these two Image constructors? And where are you're images located relative to your class?

Comment: I have resource folder and within is CSS folder and within it is image. So Absolute path is D:/workspace/mazeGame/resources/CSS/nova_hra.png.

And my fail, there should be 
When I used

buttonNewGame.setBackground(new Background(newGameBgr));
the whole image disapeard.

Comment: Because `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` loads a resource relative to your current class. `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` loads a resource relative to your class path root. So you are probably just using the wrong path, have you verified that your stream != null?

Comment: I am sure my path is all right becasose when i use 
Image newGame = new Image("File:/CSS/nova_hra.png"); the image is loaded. I am not sure how to verify the stream != null. Everytime I am trying to load image as stream I got runtimeException.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it via css. If your background.jpg is in a package testing, simply do this:

```
    package testing;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Main extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

            try {

                Pane root = new Pane();

                Button button = new Button( "Click me!");
                button.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/testing/background.jpg')");

                root.getChildren().add(button);

                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 400);
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

If you don't want to use css, you could do it like this:

```
        BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage( new Image( getClass().getResource("/testing/background.jpg").toExternalForm()), BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
        Background background = new Background(backgroundImage);

        Button button = new Button( "Click me!");
        button.setBackground(background);
```

Comment: O thanks, I moved images from resources folder to the package and then used CSS kode and it works - tons of thanks :)