# How can I display images on buttons that are attached to TilePane

Tags: javafx-8

-JavaFX

I created an array of buttons and attached them to tilePane. Now, I want to display an image on each button. I need some sort of an array of images that has the same size as the array buttons so that I can allocate an image for each button and display it. Meaning I need every button to display its own image.

I am coding in JavaFX. I'm struggling to create an array of images so that they can be displayed on the buttons. Please note that I want to display images on each button #not display images when I click the button.

```
        public class Main extends Application {
            private static Image[] deck = new Image[35];
            private static ImageView[] imageView = new ImageView[35];

            @Override
            public void start(Stage LoginWindow) {
                Button[] btn = new Button[35];
                Controller control = new Controller();
                for (int s = 0; s < 35; s++) {
                    btn[s] = new Button();
                    btn[s].setPrefSize(262, 200);
                    btn[s].setOnAction(e -> control.display());
                    btn[s].setStyle("-fx-border-color: #10fffa; -fx-border-width: 5px;");

                }

                TilePane pane = new TilePane();
                pane.setPadding(new Insets(20, 10, 20, 10));
                pane.setHgap(10);
                pane.setVgap(10);
                pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                pane.setMaxSize(500, 700);
                pane.getChildren().addAll(btn);
                Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 700);
                LoginWindow.setFullScreen(true);
                LoginWindow.setScene(scene);
                LoginWindow.show();
            }
            public void add() {
                for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
                    deck[i] = new Image(i + ".png");
                    imageView[i].setImage(deck[i]);
            }
    }
}
```

When I run the code it should display images on every button. Images can differ. No action Listeners. Just buttons with images on a TilePane.

Comment: You could simply set the `graphic` of each `Button` to be the appropriate `ImageView`. This doesn't require a separate array, unless there's a reason you need the `ImageView[]`? Note, depending on what you want, you could set the `background` of your `Button`, using a `BackgroundImage`, instead of the `graphic`.

Comment: On the example I sent I created an array of 35 buttons. So, doing them one by one is going to make me repeat the same code like 35 times setting each to the appropriate. Also reading the images one by one is going to be too long. If the number grows to 100 buttons then it's going to be longer hence I wanted to create a method using arrays and loops. Please help me if possible.

Comment: Meaning I must create an array of images and an array of buttons with the same size. Then put them in a method so that I can show all the number of images at once without reading them individually.

Comment: What I meant is you could set the `graphic` (or `background)` while you're creating your `Button`s—in the same loop. The problem here is knowing how to resolve a different image for each button. One solution is to name you resources something like `button-image-<i>` where `<i>` is replaced with a number in the range `[0, N)` (`N` being the number of images). Then you'd build the resource name using the current loop index. Another solution is to simply store the resource names in some constant array/list somewhere and loop through them simultaneously (this allows for better resource names).

Comment: Thank you... Let me try that and I'll get back to you

Comment: Please help me check if the first line of the code because IntelliJ is complaining about it but I'm not sure what is the problem.                                                                                https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985284/12005906